# How do I create hyperlinks properly using python's docxtpl?

Tags: python-3.x, templates, ms-word, hyperlink, docx

I am working on a process to automate the generation of a report. I read the documentation on how to create hyperlinks in RichText and I tried following it ([1](https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/blob/master/tests/richtext.py), [2](https://docxtpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)), but in the generated documents the hyperlink does not show up.

I have **{{r rt}}** in my template where I would like to insert the hyperlinks and my code is

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate, InlineImage, RichText

doc = DocxTemplate(report_template)
context_to_load = {}

rt = RichText()
rt.add('eHYD Link', url_id=doc.build_url_id('https://ehyd.gv.at/'))

context_to_load['rt'] = rt

doc.render(context_to_load)
doc.save(report_output)
```

And my output looks like this 
[image: My output]

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, my code in the question is working! The problem was that my word was in the "Show field code instead of their values"! Alt + F9 solved my problem...

[image]